# Using MacPorts-installed Python packages with Enthought(or some other) Python on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, emacs, macports, enthought

I have two installations of Python 2.7.2 -- from MacPorts and Enthought -- on my Mac. I use the Enthought Python as the primary one; however, the MacPorts distribution has several additional packages like pymacs, rope etc., which I would like to make available to the Enthought Python. (I'm actually trying to use Emacs w/ Enthought Python, but also make use of the MacPorts-installed Rope, Pymacs for code completion in Emacs).

Is there a clean way to make the MacPorts packages available to the Enthought Python without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's risky trying to combine the two distributions, as you are likely to get conflicts (especially for C-extensions linked to slightly different versions of shared libraries).  This is a common cause of problems with EPD:

https://support.enthought.com/entries/22094157-OS-X-Conflict-with-installed-packages-in-earlier-Python-installation

The recommended way to install new packages in EPD is with the `enpkg` tool.  You can find out more about enpkg with `enpkg --help` or in this article:

https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-EPD-packages

If your package isn't available through enpkg (in your case it looks like `rope` is while `pymacs` is not, assuming you have an appropriate subscription), EPD is a very standard python distribution, and you can install packages in it through normal means such as `pip` or by grabbing the source and running `python setup.py install`.  See:

https://support.enthought.com/entries/22914233-Using-non-EPD-package-installers-such-as-pip

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to install the additional packages once more for the Enthought Python. Trying to reuse packages from another installation seems neither clean nor safe to me.